# Spotfire Dense rank sorting via custom expression

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I am working with a dataset in Spotfire that has several replicates of multiple test articles being run through several sets of conditions, with a single final readout column. i.e.
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXPkO.png)

In this example I am trying to rank my results to make the end graphs more digestible. I started with limiting the data set to only the conditions that I want through the "Limit Data through a custom expression" panel. Then set up a denserank function in a custom expression on the x axis to sort the values into a smooth curve. The expression I am trying is:

DenseRank(Avg([Lum/OD]) OVER ([MOLECULE_ID]), "asc") which results in the following graph:
[Graph Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3vhM.png)

Could anyone explain why the displayed data doesn't rank in an ascending curve? I'm sure I'm missing something with how the custom expression is applied, but I don't see what.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the Y axis as

```
Avg([Lum/OD]) over ([MOLECULE_ID])
```

Avg([Lum/OD]) by itself using your sample data lines up all markers to the same level, so I am not sure what happens in the graph you showed - where the markers are at different heights. The Y axis looks like a label in your graph, what was the underlying expression?

Comment: Apologies. Youre correct, the Y is label. the underlying equation is the one you mentioned.

Comment: so is it the one with the average over the molecule or without? If it is with the over, then I don't understand how it looks in your graph

Comment: The y axis eq is Avg([Lum/OD]) over ([MOLECULE_ID]). It seems like this is not an easily explained behavior, and Spotfires documentation hasnt been helpful either

Comment: maybe it is your limit by expression?

Comment: This might be it. I removed the data limiter equation, and then added back in sections of it one at a time and most of them break the sorting.

i.e. I could keep a filter on the Molecule column, but not on the time, conc, or temp columns. Any of those 3 immediately break the sorting. 

Unfortunately, I am new to spotfire. Is there another way to separate out subsets of data? A way to know what columns you are able to filter on while preserving the function of the sorting method?

Comment: You could try a filter (from the filter panel) but without a representative sample and more information it is difficult to help.  I see you posted this question to the TIBCO Community site and got a lot of comments there too. Maybe you could open a support case to preserve data confidentiality.

Comment: Yes, between here and that post I made some progress. Thank you for all the help. The suggestion of the data filtering appears to be part of the issue. Unfortunately not all of it. I will continue to troubleshoot as best I can and also try submitting a support ticket.